# Dymanic content in print pages with running header and footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m printing report which is dynamically generated, the report consist of dynamically generated table.

While I’m printing multiple pages, the header and footer are appearing in first and last page only. I need to print it in each and every page and the content should not overlap the header and footer.

I tried @page rule(w3c) , but its not working.

My main need is, it should in all browsers (IE 11.0, Firefox 29.0.1, Chrome 35.0, Opera 17.0, Safari 5.1.7)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Layout</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  header {
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
  }
  footer {
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>I am a header</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce a ligula dolor.
    </p>
  </article>
  <footer>
    <h4>I am a footer</h4>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pKvxN/)

Comment: Sorry Cracker its not working. Any way thank you for your support.